# Standalone Cesium Timeline Widget

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

Has anyone taken the time to extract the timeline widget from the Cesium app? I'm looking to use the timeline widget without the Dojo dependency. I was able to find a teaser saying that it's possible, but the timeline example isn't the easiest to reverse engineer. Does anyone have an idea of how I can extract the necessary libraries and remove the Dojo dependency?

[google groups timeline discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cesium-dev/H4BdJ-2fh7s)

[cesium timeline demo](http://cesiumjs.org/releases/b20/Apps/TimelineDemo/index.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The timeline itself (outside of that demo app) does not use Dojo.  Here's a sample of how this works.  You can [Run this demo on Sandcastle](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=lVPLbtswEPwVQhfJgEKh7dGK0dTIIUXaHhL0pAstrmMiFCnwIcMp8u9d0pIRhWrR6iJyd2a5O+TsvWqd0Ipo9Sg6kELBQ2v8bj/GC1iRX40iZGCGtFK3z+SaAI2rdYjHFW29MaBcKBHzDhdfvRRMvQHZg/aS3yjRMRdgeyYtYP61UY0K9QNrq5UzWtrwZ9iNQSDXre+wPH0CdyshLL+c7niRLxLy1fpcbmpXwZFswQrf0W0IFTPATwHHb5qDXEBeckWETjwWR0B1FptsDeB8Y59FzsUQO0pJqCKz9juLmuVtPPdqwCPBXKXoHGsszktZ34Pi24OQvEh5SdPzOW+m8AK1XAS+E+WyXU0nufEh/Y86Cedv4iTgf9Mmob1veK7M5IeUV5LLc5hylHF+O+BI98I6QEyRW3Ahm5d/8lZ5dsCszIvW3aMuRsM4ZqKnyslBTvdhHyhz8RNzOeODtxp1FIrrI8Vu7pQDMzBZXMw9evtc3InRGq8l+fRxtc7KrLbuJGETMJ9F12vjiDeyoLRy0PUST7LVzrfPgPdqbeDW1USp8WqJ4NdNtngzTUbiDWN+76V8EC/QZJu6QtaMLDXjQj39GMBIdgqQw4fN/TlIKa0r3KYsp7XcMfOmIsHvNw).

```js
function onTimelineScrubfunction(e) {
  var clock = e.clock;
  clock.currentTime = e.timeJulian;
  clock.shouldAnimate = false;
}

var timeControlsContainer = document.getElementById('timeControlsContainer');
var clock = new Cesium.Clock();
var clockViewModel = new Cesium.ClockViewModel(clock);
var animationContainer = document.createElement('div');
animationContainer.className = 'cesium-viewer-animationContainer';
timeControlsContainer.appendChild(animationContainer);
var animation = new Cesium.Animation(animationContainer, new Cesium.AnimationViewModel(clockViewModel));
var timelineContainer = document.createElement('div');
timelineContainer.className = 'cesium-viewer-timelineContainer';
timeControlsContainer.appendChild(timelineContainer);
var timeline = new Cesium.Timeline(timelineContainer, clock);
timeline.addEventListener('settime', onTimelineScrubfunction, false);
timeline.zoomTo(clock.startTime, clock.stopTime);
clockViewModel.shouldAnimate = true;


window.setInterval(function() {
  clock.tick();
}, 32);
```